# Child nodes doesn't remove on mobile browsers

Tags: angular, typescript, mobile, removechild, aframe

I make a virtual guide using A-frame in combination with Angular and use next code to remove all hot spots and navigation arrows from the `a-entity` tag.

```
while (this.hotSpotEntity.hasChildNodes()) {
    this.hotSpotEntity.removeChild(this.hotSpotEntity.childNodes[0]);
}

while (this.navigationEntity.hasChildNodes()) {
    this.navigationEntity.removeChild(this.navigationEntity.childNodes[0]);
}
```

This code will remove all elements from the `a-entity` tags I've defined as global variables. But there is an issue with this code.

**P.S.:** Can't use databinding because A-frame doesn't support it .

See this first scene below. The arrows and magnifiers are added by the code I've written and are children of the `hotspotEntity` and `navigationEntity`.

[image: screenshot_20170329-142718]

I've I click on a arrow, the code navigates you to a new scene. But you could see that the arrows and hotspots aren't removed. This are the red striped images. The green circled image is added after navigating.

[image: screenshot_20170329-142735]

When you click on the green circled arrow, you're navigating to the next scene. Here you could see that the images from the first sky aren't removed but the images of the second scene are removed.

[image: screenshot_20170329-145030]

The bug happens only on mobile browsers *(Google Chrome for Android, Samsung Internet)* and not on desktop browsers *(Firefox, Edge)*.

Could anyone why this bug occurs only on mobile browsers and how I could solve it?

You could test the tour on this link: http://student.howest.be/hein.pauwelyn-vand1/poppr/aframe/ and full code on [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/HeinPauwelyn/10f3c6948f330eb6f6df01bcc1587c1a).

Comment: are maybe you using an ES2015 features that aren't available on mobile? are you possibly forgetting a polyfill? are you not using babel to transpile to ES5?

Comment: @RicoKahler I'm using the arrow notation `() => { ... }`. I go place my full code online.

Comment: Are you using babel to transpile those to ES5?

Comment: @RicoKahler no, I use Angular-cli `ng build` and `ng serve` commands.

Comment: I would just try replacing your arrow functions with normal `function`s and see if it works. If that solves your problem then you can add babel to your project setup.

Comment: OH WAIT I'm stupid. you're using typescript which compiles to ES5. you don't need babel. my bad. in your `tsconfig.json`, is your compile target ES5?

Comment: @RicoKahler: yes it must be compiled to ES5

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something a little different:

```
while (this.hotSpotEntity.firstChild) {
   this.hotSpotEntity.removeChild(this.hotSpotEntity.firstChild);
}

while (this.navigationEntity.firstChild) {
    this.navigationEntity.removeChild(this.navigationEntity.firstChild);
}
```

[`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) is a readonly property that will return `null` if there isn't one. You can use it in the condition because it's truthy when there is a child and falsy when there isn't.

If this works on mobile and fixes the bug, then I don't know why unfortunately. <strike>Let me know if this doesn't solve your problem. I'll delete the answer.</strike>

Comment: No it doesn't work. PS: Don't delete this answer because other people could see that this doesn't work.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn that's a good idea. I was just thinking of deleting because I see this as more of a comment with the potential of solving the problem lol. best of luck

Comment: Weird. Maybe try `this.navigationEntity.innerHTML = ''`? Do you detect children when you run that code?